# sfdx Invalid Cross Reference id pushing app to scratch org

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, sfdx-plugin

When I attempt to push my sfdx project to the source, I've been having issues with the app metadata files.

1. Download content assets via XML source pull.
2. Add MasterLabel to the app metadata brand in the tag
3. sfdx force:source:push -u myScratchOrg

> Result: Error: invalid cross reference id

Comment: check this references: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/201837/salesforce-dx-pushing-profiles-gives-invalid-cross-reference-id

Comment: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000mCIdQAM&title=invalid-cross-reference-id-deploying-custom-app-with-profileactionoverrides-referencing-new-profiles-in-same-deployment